# Не пойму, что значит <=

Tags: c++

Просвятите меня, пожалуйста :)

Comment: "просв**я**тите"?

Comment: @AnT как почетный святой, почетный великомученик, ...

Comment: @andy.37 https://www.technofresh.ru/galleries/2007_02/article/pn03.jpg?__scale=w:200,h:218,t:4,c:FFFFFF

Comment: @AnT Вообще такой вопрос следует закрыть. Ну ладно, новому участнику прощается.

Comment: @VerNick ну я думаю это не правильно. Стоит пояснить человеку как нужно. А не _прощать_ ему что бы ошибки в пользовании форума повторялись

Comment: @SeeSharp Ну хорошо, я согласен. Только он куда-то смылся и не появляется.

Comment: @VerNick это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Не хотели ли вы принять ответ? (кликните на галочку справа от ответа, который вам подходит, вам +2,  тому кто ответил +15).

Answer (score 3):

#### Меньше или равно

*Оператор меньше или равно*, возвращает истину в том случае, если значение операнда слева меньше, или равно значению операнда справа.

#### Синтаксис

```
x <= y
```

#### Примеры:

```
3 <= 4 // истина
3 <= 3 // истина
3 <= 2 // ложь
```

Такие сравнения обычно испульзуют в условном операторе `if()`:

```
if(3 <= 4){
    cout << "Меньше или равно";
}
```

Либо заносят результат от сравнения `true` или `false` в переменную типа `bool`:

```
bool n = 3 <= 4; // значение будет true
cout << n;
```

Ну до этого вам еще далеко :) Так что пока о последнем примере не думайте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85508/discussion-between-genesis-and-ver-nick).

Comment: @GENESIS Да я же вам объяснил, надо развернутый ответ писать а не "ну так то это меньше или равно на всех языках". Новичок в программировании поймет, что ли что вы хотите этим сказать?

Answer (score 0):

ну так то это меньше или равно на всех языках)

```
<= меньше или равно

<<= составной поразрядный сдвиг влево
```

Comment: А скоро будет еще `<=>` :)

Comment: @AnT А что это будет значить? Меньше, больше и равно?

Comment: <> такой уже есть знак)

Comment: @Ver Nick: Да, это будет значить "тернарное сравнение", в стиле сравнений языка С (см. `strcmp`). Причем оператор `<=>`, если он определен, будет также использоваться для неявной генерации  всех остальных операторов сравнения.

Comment: @AnT Занятно :)

Comment: @GENESIS: Что значит "<> такой уже есть знак"?

Comment: @AnT Зачем вы ставите двоеточие после ника?

Comment: @Ver Nick: Так вроде бы, всегда делалось на SO. Мобильное приложение SO этого не делает, но "десктопные" участники SO обычно его ставят.

Comment: @AnT Ну не знаю, я декстопный, и без двоеточия все ок.

Comment: угловые скобки))))

Comment: @GENESIS: Угловые скобки - это два отдельных "знака", а не один "знак".